# How do I write a function to multiple numbers from 1-10?

Tags: javascript, multiplication

```
var a = 7;
var b;

for (var i = 1; i <= 10 ; i++) {

    b = a * i;
    
    document.write(" " +a+ "*",  + b + "<br>");
}
```

This works however it has to be a loop, not code for one specific number so I need to write it so it goes for all numbers 1 through 10.

I'm using http://js.do which we have to use.

Comment: OK, then you just need to replace `var a = 7` with a loop from a = 1 to a <= 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have two loops - one nested inside the other - both going from 1 to 10.

Something like:

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  for (let j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
    let s = i * j;
    document.write(i + "*" + j + "=" + s + "<br>");
  }
}
```

Or, to allow the user to enter a number of their choice:

```js
let a = prompt("Enter a number: ");
if (a) {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    let b = i * a;
    document.write(a + "*" + i + "=" + b + "<br>");
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked however is it possible to have a window pop up which allows me to chose an input like 7 and then that multiplication table shows up instead of having all of them at the same time

Comment: Yep - see the second snippet

Comment: Really appreciate the help, had a problem with the prompt!

Comment: Did that solve your question?

Comment: Yes, it definitely did

Comment: OK - you should probably flag my Answer as correct so that others know that you now have what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a;
var b;
  
for (var a = 1; a <= 10 ; a++) {  // loop the a number 1 to 10
  for (var i = 1; i <= 10 ; i++) {

    b = a * i;
    
    document.write(" " +a+ "*",  + b + "<br>");
  }
}
```

Comment: `var a = 7;` is now obsolete